# Some questions about saving images via PHP

Tags: php, image

I want to save images via PHP.
My code is like this:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng("myimage.png");
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

if ($width == 0) {
    $thumb_width = 0;
    $thumb_height = 0;
} else {
    $thumb_width = 600;
    $thumb_height = (int)(600 * $height / $width);
}

$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
   // If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
   $new_height = $thumb_height;
   $new_width = (int)($width / ($height / $thumb_height));
}
else
{
   // If the thumbnail is wider than the image
   $new_width = $thumb_width;
   $new_height = $thumb_height;
}

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

// Resize and crop
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                   $image,
                   0, 0,
                   0, 0,
                   $new_width, $new_height,
                   $width, $height);
imagejpeg($thumb, "newimage.jpg", 80);
```

1. There is a problem, that the newimage.jpg is much darker of the png - Why, and what shall I do in order to save it properly.
2. Is there any way saving the newimage.jpg with a new opacity? - How can I do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: To save the colours ok + the opacity, you should save as PNG. Why are you saving as JPG?

Comment: try asking one question each time. also change your question title to reflect the question content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of GD that your version of PHP is using doesn't support color profiles.

It's a real issue if you can't update the server, and is annoyingly common.

Comment: Thank you.
About opacity - I have managed, using imagecopymerg.

About second case (the dark png) - what I do is uploading some images, as clients requests, and I don't want to limit the types of images.

Thanks :)